# NoClassDefFoundError while testing azure purview SDK for Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-purview

I'm following this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/purview/azure-analytics-purview-catalog/src/samples/java/com/azure/analytics/purview/catalog/ListGlossaries.java) to test purview SDK for java, it could be built successful, but when I run this java file ,it shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher". the class "DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder" was defined in core-identity jar and I already imported it ,not clear why it still failed and what class it required?

[image]

here is my code content

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We get this error when the class is not available in the program at runtime but class was successfully compiled by the java compiler.

The reason why you are getting this error is because of  jre  unable to find  **DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder** class.

As you mentioned in the post that this class is defined inside core-identity jar. whether  the jar file may be missing. So, try to import it again and check.